# Is there a typo in this sentence? If not, help me understand it

Tags: errors, syntactic-analysis

I'm having trouble parsing this sentence:  *(I hope I used "parsing" correctly.)*

> Now, the history of Eliza Doolittle, though called a romance because
>   of the transfiguration it records seems exceedingly improbable, is
>   common enough.

*from the epilogue to Shaw's* Pygmalion.  [Full text](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3825/3825-h/3825-h.htm).

Comment: What do you think the typo is? Is *romance* as a noun for a genre or novel tripping you up? If so, maybe just [scanning a few of its glosses](http://onelook.com/?w=romance%3Anoun&ls=a) will clear up your confusion.

Comment: Keep in mind that Shaw had some singular notions about spelling and punctuation. Often with Shaw, things that look like typographical errors are authorial idiosyncrasies.

Comment: I think the issue here is with "though called a romance because of the transfiguration it records seems exceedingly improbable". To my eye, it should either be "because of the transfiguration it records seeming exceedingly improbable" or "because the transfiguration it records seems exceedingly improbable". It needs to either remove the "of" or change "seems" to "seeming" to be grammatically correct.

Comment: I want to insert commas for my own use, but still hold on to the idea Shaw was trying to convey.  I've tried to do that with this sentence but I can't get it to work.  Maybe I need to remove a word or two?

Comment: The "of" after "because" needs to be removed. I'm also confused by your use of "though"; the statement seems to be implying that the "common" history of Eliza Doolittle would make it less likely to be considered a romance. I don't see how those two things are mutually exclusive. My gut feeling is that this sentence needs to be completely rewritten to get your point across, but I'm not sure what your point is yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an OCR error in more recent ebook versions of Shaw's text. If you check Google Books you'll find all earlier versions have *because the transfiguration* (no ***of***, so OP would completely misinterpret things if he kept that and tried to "fix" things with an additional comma later).

Comment: @TimWard I may be incorrect, but I don't think the OP is Bernard Shaw. :P

Comment: @JohnClifford I would expect better of Mr. Shaw. :P

Comment: ...unless... what if there's an implied *comma* after "records"...? Although there's an abundance of commas elsewhere and I'm not sure why it would have been omitted there (other than to cause generations to ask what he meant when he said that)...

Comment: In other words, what if the quote is really saying: "Now, the history of Eliza Doolittle -- though called a romance because of the transfiguration it records -- seems exceedingly improbable, ..."

Comment: @TimWard Then the "is common enough" doesn't fit.

Comment: @JohnClifford, yep, saw that afterward and wondered if the whole thing could be a perpetuated typo... I still wonder if the hyphenated part I proposed might make more sense than the original print.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is an *of* too much. I should think it a typo.

Comment: Yeah, there are two or three ways to reword it, but that clause is not right, by the standards of modern US English, at least.

Answer (score 1):

A Google Books search confirms FumbleFingers's observation (in a comment above) that the preposition *of* at the twelfth word of the quoted sentence is almost certainly an optical character recognition error introduced in recent electronic versions of *Pygmalion*. The error is strikingly widespread—a Google Books search returns six confirmable instances of the sentence with the stray *of* present, from six different e-publishers, all dated 2015 or 2016—but that only emphasizes the echo chamber effect of online content.

A search for the sentence with the stray *of* omitted returns eighteen matches—the earliest one being from [1932](https://books.google.com/books?id=XwEMAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Doolittle+though+called+a+romance+because+the%22&dq=%22Doolittle+though+called+a+romance+because+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ1Z3I3fXKAhVU62MKHQrNDygQ6AEILjAD) and the most recent from [2014](https://books.google.com/books?id=HGUSBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA107&dq=%22Doolittle+though+called+a+romance+because+the%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ1Z3I3fXKAhVU62MKHQrNDygQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22Doolittle%20though%20called%20a%20romance%20because%20the%22&f=false) (citing the 1969 Penguin reprint of the play). Pygmalian was first produced in 1914 and first published in 1916.